# Huge pages for memory mapped files on Linux

Tags: c, linux, mmap, tlb, huge-pages

I want to use Huge Pages with memory-mapped files on Linux 3.13.

To get started, on Ubuntu I did this to allocate 10 huge pages:

```
sudo apt-get install hugepages
sudo hugeadm --pool-pages-min=2048K:10
```

Then I ran this test program:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t size = 2 * 1024 * 1024; /* 1 huge page */

    int fd = open("foo.bar", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
    assert(fd >= 0);
    int rc = ftruncate(fd, size);
    assert(rc == 0);

    void* hint = 0;
    int flags = MAP_SHARED | MAP_HUGETLB;
    void* data = mmap(hint, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, flags, fd, 0);
    if (data == MAP_FAILED)
        perror("mmap");
    assert(data != MAP_FAILED);
}
```

It always fails with EINVAL.  If you change `flags` to `MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS` then it works, but of course it won't write anything to the file.

I also tried using `madvise()` after `mmap()` without `MAP_HUGETLB`:

```
    rc = madvise(data, size, MADV_HUGEPAGE);
    if (rc != 0)
        perror("madvise");
    assert(rc == 0);
```

This also fails (`EINVAL`) if `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is not used.

**Is there any way to enable huge pages with memory-mapped files on disk?**

To be clear, I am looking for a way to do this in C--I'm not asking for a solution to apply to existing executables (then the question would belong on SuperUser).

Comment: I have been trying similar stuff - without luck. If you come up with a solution, please share :) BTW: Have you read this QA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470972/using-mmap-and-madvise-for-huge-pages It doesn't solve my problem but it provides a link to some kernel documentation. I tried to follow that documentation - still without any luck but perhaps you can make something of it.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a way to do this?

Comment: @Mehnaz: No, but I have not tried since 2017.

Comment: Did you use any alternative?

Comment: I don't know of any alternative apart from perhaps using a filesystem other than ext4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the underlying filesystem you are using does not support memory-mapping files using huge pages.

For example, for ext4 this support is still under development [as of January 2017](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=148543199403944), and not included in the kernel yet (as of May 19, 2017).

If you run a kernel with that patchset applied, do note that you need to enable huge page support in the filesystem mount options, for example adding `huge=always` to the fourth column in `/etc/fstab` for the filesystems desired, or using `sudo mount -o remount,huge=always /mountpoint`.

Comment: Is this still unsupported in ext4?

Answer (score 1):

There is a confusion here: Huge pages can be used through the raw kernel interface or/and through a user space library (*libhugetlbfs*) and accompanying tools (e.g. `hugeadm`).

If you want to `mmap()` a memory zone into huge pages. You are using the "raw kernel interface". To make it, there is a recipe in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64914391/14393739).

If you want to use the user space library (*libhugetlbfs*), get help from the [manuals of the tools](https://linux.die.net/man/8/hugeadm) and the [manual of the API](https://linux.die.net/man/7/libhugetlbfs).

Comment: Is it possible to do a file-backed mmap with the MAP_HUGETLB flag?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible. The huge pages are dedicated to reduce page faults and TLB misses using consecutive physical pages. This is typically used to make a dynamic memory allocator more efficient, map thread stacks into it or share big chunks of memory between processes.